# Find the third-highest salary in each department

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to find the **third-highest salary** in **each department** if there is such.

[image]

```
SELECT DepartmentID
FROM Employees
GROUP BY DepartmentID
```

This is what I can do.

I looked at similar posts but not sure I understand how to do it with my table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use row_number function to assign a order of salary, then get the 3rd one:

```
SELECT s.DepartmentID, s.Salary
FROM (
SELECT DepartmentID, Salary, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DepartmentID ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS salary_rank
FROM Employees) s
WHERE s.salary_rank=3
```

Comment: What if salary has duplicate value department wise. For that we need to use DENSE_RANK() function and TOP (1) clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   e.first_name,
         e.last_name,
         d.department_name,
         salary,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY d.id ORDER BY salary DESC ) AS 
         salary_rank 
FROM     department d 
JOIN     employee e ON d.id = e.department_id 
ORDER BY department_name;
```